# How to restart SESSION based on session ID from external PHP

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to integrate SWFUpload into Joomla (customized implementation, and this is why cannot use extensions with swfupload).

I am passing through SWFUpload the ID if SESSION and on server side I need to get all data of $_SESSION for the passed ID.

This is the code I have (direct script access):
based on [this tutorial](http://jeffbrand.net/programming/using-session-cookies-with-swfupload-despite-the-bug-in-adobes-flash-plugin/)

```
if (isset($_POST["PHPSESSID"])) {
    session_write_close();             // End the previously-started session
    session_id($_POST["PHPSESSID"]);   // Set the new session ID
    session_start();                   // Start it
}
```

and here is the error I get in SWFUpload debug window:

```
Fatal error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: /var/lib/php5) in /srv/www/htdocs_appsrv/.../incoming.php on line 19
```

Line 19 is

```
session_start();
```

How can I restart a session having session ID and then grab all needed data from $_SESSION?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the code below seems to work

```
if (isset($_POST["PHPSESSID"])) {
    session_write_close();             // End the previously-started session
    $jd = new JSessionStorageDatabase();
    session_id($_POST["PHPSESSID"]);   // Set the new session ID
    session_start();                   // Start it
}
```

I found that based on [this tutorial](http://pribadidewa.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/session-management-in-joomla/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
JFactory::getSession()->destroy();
```